# What files must be ignored by Git using Gradle?

Tags: android, git, gradle

Right now I'm going to learn how to use [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle).

I'm using the Git [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). What files and folders must be added to the .gitignore file so they must be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what gitignore.io [suggests](http://www.gitignore.io/api/gradle):

```
# Created by http://www.gitignore.io

### Gradle ###
.gradle
build/
```

[gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io/) is a useful site for generating `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` files. It even has command line integration, so you could do something like

```
gi gradle >> .gitignore
```